# How to convert a script into SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to convert the script below into a SQLite database named MobileSell.db.

How can I achieve that?

I have the following script with extension `.sql`:

```
SELECT 1;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE [routes] (
  [routeid] bigint  NOT NULL
, [routename] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_routes_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);
CREATE TABLE [groups] (
  [groupid] nvarchar(6)  NOT NULL
, [name] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_groups_1] PRIMARY KEY ([groupid])
);
CREATE TABLE [dept] (
  [deliveryid] bigint  NULL
, [deliverydate] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [debtid] nvarchar(20)  NOT NULL
, [debtsum] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [oldpay] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [presentpay] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [restsum] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [enddate] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_dept_1] PRIMARY KEY ([deptid])
);
CREATE TABLE [customers] (
  [id] bigint  NOT NULL
, [company] nvarchar(60)  NULL
, [taxnumber] nvarchar(13)  NULL
, [vatnumber] nvarchar(15)  NULL
, [address] nvarchar(60)  NULL
, [recipient] nvarchar(60)  NULL
, [discount] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [dept] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [object] nvarchar(50)  NULL
, [subject] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [objectaddress] nvarchar(50)  NULL
, [person] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [typeprice] int  NULL
, [route] bigint  NULL
, [model] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [city] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [region] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [dealer] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [segment] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [agreement] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [assembly] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [dateassembly] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [phone] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [recipe] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [lastselldate] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [lastquantity] int  NULL
, [segment_id] nvarchar(10)  NULL
, [mstate] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [refid] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [rowflqg] smallint NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_customers_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);
CREATE TABLE [cashbook] (
  [id] int  NOT NULL
, [date] datetime NULL
, [income] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [expense] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [note] nvarchar(34)  NULL
, [category] nvarchar(10)  NULL
, [subcategory] nvarchar(10)  NULL
, [paymenttype] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [docnumber] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [categoryname] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [subcategoryname] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_cashbook_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);
CREATE TABLE [articles] (
  [id] nvarchar(12)  NOT NULL
, [name] nvarchar(60)  NULL
, [quantity] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [sell_price] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [sellid] nvarchar(6)  NULL
, [whole_price] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [group] nvarchar(6)  NULL
, [barcode] nvarchar(30)  NULL
, [measure] nvarchar(5)  NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_articles_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);
CREATE TABLE [sertif] (
  [artid] nvarchar(9)  NULL
, [name] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [quantiry] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [lotid] nvarchar(20)  NULL
, [expire_date] nvarchar(30) NULL
, FOREIGN KEY ([artid]) REFERENCES [articles] ([id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON 
UPDATE NO ACTION);
CREATE TABLE [custdisc] (
  [customerid] bigint  NULL
, [group] nvarchar(9)  NULL
, [discount] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, [price] numeric(53,0)  NULL
, FOREIGN KEY ([artid]) REFERENCES [articles] ([id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON 
UPDATE NO ACTION
, FOREIGN KEY ([customerid]) REFERENCES [customers] ([id]) ON DELETE NO 
ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
CREATE INDEX [routes_id_index] ON [routes] ([id] ASC);
CREATE INDEX [customers_id_index] ON [customers] ([id] ASC);
CREATE INDEX [cashbook_id_index] ON [cashbook] ([id] ASC);
CREATE INDEX [artictes_id_index] ON [articles] ([id] ASC);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your ".sql" file is named "dump.sql" and has correct SQLite syntax and not logical error or broken references,
then you can run the file from a commandline by calling the commandline version of SQLite3, like this:

```
sqlite3.exe -init dump.sql MobileSell.db
```

Do so while the current workig directory is that folder (and have the sqlite3.exe in your `PATH` environment variable or prepend the full absolute path to the exe).

This assumes Windows as environment (mine).
The same should work almost identically in other environments, apart from things like ".exe".

Your file however gives then some errors:

```
Error: near line 4: no such column: id
Error: near line 14: no such column: deptid
Error: near line 92: unknown column "artid" in foreign key definition
Error: near line 101: no such table: main.routes
```

You can avoid those errors, if you change

```
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_routes_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
```

->

```
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_routes_1] PRIMARY KEY ([routeid])
```

and

```
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_dept_1] PRIMARY KEY ([deptid])
```

->

```
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_dept_1] PRIMARY KEY ([debtid])
```

and

```
[customerid] bigint  NULL
```

->

```
[artid] nvarchar(9)  NULL
, [customerid] bigint  NULL
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX [routes_id_index] ON [routes] ([id] ASC);

CREATE INDEX [routes_id_index] ON [routes] ([routeid] ASC);
```

Then you get output "1" without errors and inside the current working directory you will have the desired file "MobileSell.db" with the created database (and next to it still the script file "dump.sql").

You will still be in sqlite prompt afterwards. Use e.g. `.tables` command to verify success. Then use `.quit` command to exit the sqlite prompt.

In case you are inexperienced with using command line tools, use three absolute paths; to the exe, to the script and to where the db should end up.

```
<baspathtoexe>\sqlite3.exe -init <abspathtoscript>\dump.sql <abspathtodbtargetfolder>\MobileSell.db
```

You will have to check yourself whether the purpose of the database is then still intact.

Comment: Where do I put the script content?

Comment: You mean where to put the content of the script file you mentioned? I do not see what you are asking. I assume that you have the posted script inside, well a file with a file name ending in ".sql". I assumed "dump.sql", because that is what the posted lines look like.

Comment: I tried my answer being inside an initially empty folder in my file system, where I created a file with the name "dump.sql" and the content which I copied from your question. Then, with the current working directory being that folder with the freshly created file, I executed the commandline from my answer.

Comment: How to convert the script into file with extension .db? And then I want to import it into SQLite Server Compact Toolbox in Visual Studio.

Comment: My answer explains how to do that (more explicitly now, after an edit). You start with only having the script, you end with having the script and next to it the freshly created "MobileSell.db".

Comment: Where do I put that line: `sqlite3.exe -init dump.sql MobileSell.db`

Comment: You call it from a commandline (aka DOSprompt, aka Powershell).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163379/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-profile2forstack).

Comment: I opened cmd and ran that command: `sqlite3.exe -init C:\Users\svetoslav\Desktop\MobileSellDBChanged MobileSell.db` And I got the following error: `sqlite3.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`